# Como fazer um cronometro com html5+css+javascript,que ao final do tempo selecionado toque(ou execute) um *.mp3

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, css3

Comecei testando com esse código HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />

</head>

<body onload="principal();">
    <audio id="audio">
            <source src="arquivo1.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
        </audio>


   <form name="form">
      <input type="text" name="cronometro" id="cron" value="00:00:00" />
      <br />
      <button type="button" onclick="setInterval('tempo()',983);return false;">Cronômetro</button>
      <br />
      <button onclick="clearTimeout(teste)">Zerar</button>
      <br />
        <div class="marginTop col-md-12 text-center center-block">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">Min</span>
                    <input id="minutos" type="number" min="0" max="59" class="form-control" placeholder="Minutos">
                </div>
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">Seg</span>
                    <input id="segundos" type="number"  min="0" max="59" class="form-control" placeholder="Segundos">
                    <input id="pause" type="hidden" value="0"  class="form-control">      <br />
                </div>
            </div>  
         </div>                 
        <button type="submit" id="marcarTempo">marcar</button> 
        <br />      
        <button type="reset" id="parar" onclick="pause()">Parar</button>      
      <br />
   </form>


<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</body>


</html>`
```

E este CSS:

```
*{
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        }
    body{
        background:#CCC;
        color:#FFF;
        font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        text-align:center;
        }
    #topo{
        background:#069;
        height:100px;
        line-height:100px;
        border-bottom:2px solid #006;
        }
    h2 a{
        color:#069;
        text-decoration:none;
        }
    h2 a:hover{
        color:#006;
        }
    input{
        background:#000;
        width:600px;
        height:200px;
        line-height:200px;
        font-size:150px;
        border:none;
        color:#ffffff;
        border-radius: 25px;
        border: 2px solid #a1a1a1;
        }
    input#minutos.form-control{
        font-size:14px;
        width: 100px;
       height: 50px;
       padding-left: 40px;


    }
    input#segundos.form-control{
       font-size:14px;
       width: 100px;
       height: 50px;    
       padding-left: 40px;


    }       
    div.input-group{
        width: 50px;
        border-bottom-width: 1px;

    }
    div.col-md-4.col-md-offset-4{
        padding-right: 650px;
    }
    div.marginTop.col-md-12.text-center.center-block{
        padding-left: 650px;
    }
```

JavaScript:

```
var segundo = 0+"0";
var minuto = 0+"0";
var hora = 0+"0";
var audio = document.getElementById('audio');

function play(){
    audio.play();
}

function tempo(){   
   if (segundo < 59){
      segundo++
      if(segundo < 10){segundo = "0"+segundo}
   }else 
      if(segundo == 59 && minuto < 59){
         segundo = 0+"0";
    minuto++;
    if(minuto < 10){minuto = "0"+minuto}
      }
   if(minuto == 59 && segundo == 59 && hora < 23){
      segundo = 0+"0";
      minuto = 0+"0";
      hora++;
      if(hora < 10){hora = "0"+hora}
   }else 
      if(minuto == 59 && segundo == 59 && hora == 23){
         segundo = 0+"0";
    minuto = 0+"0";
    hora = 0+"0";
      }
   form.cronometro.value = hora +":"+ minuto +":"+ segundo

   if(segundo == 5){
            play();
        }
function pause() {
         audio.pause();
}
}
```

Desde já agradeço!!

Answer (score 2):

Para isso basta só javascript, neste caso começa passado 3 secs:

```js
const audio = new Audio('http://homes.dcc.ufba.br/~leotavo/index.html/mp3/Coldplay%20-%20Clocks.mp3');
var timer = setTimeout(function() {
  audio.play();
}, 3000);
```

Com botão para pausar/play:

```js
const audio = new Audio('http://homes.dcc.ufba.br/~leotavo/index.html/mp3/Coldplay%20-%20Clocks.mp3');

var timer = setTimeout(function() {
  audio.play();
}, 3000);

const btn_pause = document.getElementById('pause');
const btn_play = document.getElementById('play');

btn_pause.addEventListener('click', function() {
  audio.pause();
});

btn_play.addEventListener('click', function() {
  audio.play();
});
```

```html
<button id="pause">Pausar</button>
<button id="play">Play</button>
```

Comment: obrigado! consegui de uma outra forma com a ajuda de um amigo,irei postar abaixo.

Answer (score 1):

Segue a forma que consegui...

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var divCronometro = document.getElementById("cronometro");
  var btnIniciar = document.getElementById("iniciar");
  var btnParar = document.getElementById("parar");
  var btnZerar = document.getElementById("zerar");
  var intervaloSegundos = document.getElementById("intervaloAlarme");
  new Cronometro(divCronometro, btnIniciar, btnParar, btnZerar, intervaloAlarmeMinutos, intervaloAlarmeSegundos);
}

var Cronometro = function(div, btnIniciar, btnParar, btnZerar, inputIntervaloMinutos, inputIntervaloSegundos) {
  var este = this;
  this.estado = null;
  this.hora = 0;
  this.minuto = 0;
  this.segundo = 0;
  this.intervaloAlarmeMinutos = 0;
  this.intervaloAlarmeSegundos = 0;
  this.start = false;

  // criando elemento html5 audio
  this.audio = document.createElement('audio');
  this.sourceAudio = document.createElement('source');
  this.sourceAudio.setAttribute('src', 'http://www.online-clockalarm.com/sounds/sound3.mp3');
  this.sourceAudio.setAttribute('type', 'audio/mp3');
  this.audio.appendChild(this.sourceAudio);

  this.atualizar = function() {
    var str = (este.hora < 10 ? "0" +
        este.hora : este.hora) + ":" +
      (este.minuto < 10 ? "0" + este.minuto : este.minuto) + ":" +
      (este.segundo < 10 ? "0" + este.segundo : este.segundo);
    div.innerHTML = str;
  }
  this.iniciar = function() {
    if (!este.start) {
      este.estado = setInterval(function() {
        este.segundo += 1;
        if (este.segundo % 60 == 0) {
          este.segundo = 0;
          este.minuto += 1;
        }
        if (este.minuto % 60 == 0 && este.minuto > 0) {
          este.minuto = 0;
          este.hora += 1;
        }
        este.atualizar();
        este.verificaAlarme();
      }, 1000);
      este.start = true;
    }
  }
  this.parar = function() {
    clearInterval(este.estado);
    este.start = false;
  }
  this.zerar = function() {
    este.hora = 0;
    este.minuto = 0;
    este.segundo = 0;
    este.atualizar();
  }
  this.setIntervaloAlarmeMinutos = function(minutos) {
    este.intervaloAlarmeMinutos = minutos;
  }
  this.setIntervaloAlarmeSegundos = function(segundos) {
    este.intervaloAlarmeSegundos = segundos;
  }
  this.verificaAlarme = function() {
    if (este.intervaloAlarmeMinutos != 0 || este.intervaloAlarmeSegundos != 0) {
      var segundosTotais = este.hora * 3600 + este.minuto * 60 + este.segundo;
      var intervaloAlarmeSegundosTotais = parseInt(este.intervaloAlarmeMinutos * 60) + parseInt(este.intervaloAlarmeSegundos);
      if (segundosTotais % intervaloAlarmeSegundosTotais == 0) {
        este.audio.play();
      };
    }
  }

  // Adicionando listeners
  if (document.addEventListener) {
    inputIntervaloSegundos.addEventListener("change", function() {
      este.setIntervaloAlarmeSegundos(inputIntervaloSegundos.value);
    });
    inputIntervaloMinutos.addEventListener("change", function() {
      este.setIntervaloAlarmeMinutos(inputIntervaloMinutos.value);
    });
    btnIniciar.addEventListener("click", function() {
      este.iniciar();
    });
    btnParar.addEventListener("click", function() {
      este.parar();
    });
    btnZerar.addEventListener("click", function() {
      este.zerar();
    });

  } else {
    inputIntervaloMinutos.addAttachEvent("onChange", function() {
      este.setIntervaloAlarmeMinutos(inputIntervaloMinutos.value);
    });
    inputIntervaloSegundos.addAttachEvent("onChange", function() {
      este.setIntervaloAlarmeSegundos(inputIntervaloSegundos.value);
    });
    btnIniciar.addAttachEvent("onClick", function() {
      este.iniciar();
    });
    btnParar.addAttachEvent("onClick", function() {
      c.parar();
    });
    btnZerar.addAttachEvent("onClick", function() {
      c.zerar();
    });
  }
};
```

```css
#cronometro {
  font-family: 'Courier New';
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: -10px;
  font-size: 250px;
  background: red;
  color: white;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  width: 1200px;
  margin: 6cm 4cm 1cm 3cm;
  border-radius: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

#controles {
  margin: 2cm 4cm 2cm 2cm;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 10px;
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: 160px;
  margin-left: 60px;
  margin-right: 0px;
}

body {
  background: black;
}

div#cronometro {
  width: 1200px;
}

input#intervaloAlarmeMinutos {
  margin-left: 60px;
  margin-right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="cronometro">00:00:00</div>
<div id="controles">
  <span>Definir intervalo de alarme</span>
  <p>
    <input type="number" id="intervaloAlarmeMinutos" value="0" max="60" min="0" />
    <span>Minutos</span>
    <input type="number" id="intervaloAlarmeSegundos" value="0" max="59" min="0" />
    <span>Segundos</span>
    <p>
      <button id="iniciar">Iniciar</button>
      <button id="parar">Parar</button>
      <button id="zerar">Zerar</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Você queria que ele fosse regressivo, não?

Comment: Sim! mas como disse eu refiz o código junto com um amigo e acabamos por achar melhor do forma que está";)

Comment: :) Se possivel altere o titulo da pergunta, quando alguém entrar nela pra usar como referencia, vera que não e mais regressiva rs So retire o regressivo do titulo

Answer (score 0):

Infelizmente, as respostas citando a função `setTimeout` não são muito válidas já que ela só irá executar a função se estiver livre. Ele vai esperar no minimo o tempo estipulado, mas pode levar mais tempo. Em outras palavras, ele vai atrasar a execução com facilidade.

Recomendo o uso do Plugin do jQuery [The Final Countdown](http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/),  ele é bem leve e preciso na contagem de segundos.

```
$("#SEUCONTADOR")
  .countdown("2017/01/01", function(event) {
    $(this).text(
      event.strftime('%D days %H:%M:%S')
    );
  }).on("finish.countdown", function(){
   //executa mp3

});
```

Comment: Muito brigado!!